# psycopg2.errors.ActiveSqlTransaction: CREATE TABLESPACE cannot run inside a transaction block

Tags: python, psycopg2, postgres-12

I am quite new to Python, we have an app container & a DB container. App container collects values like DB_HOST,PORT etc from CLI & try to create Tablespace on containerized Postgres DB running on same docker host.

While execution the query we are getting below error.

```
psycopg2.errors.ActiveSqlTransaction: CREATE TABLESPACE cannot run inside a transaction block
```

Python libraries used:

- `psycopg2`
- `psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT`

App Dockefile Sample

---

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache openssh sshpass && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc musl-dev && \
    apk add linux-headers && \
    apk add python3-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-client && \
    apk add bash && \
    apk add libffi-dev make

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install PyYAML==5.3.1 \
                docker==4.2.1 \
                cryptography==2.8.0 \
                docker-pycreds==0.4.0 \
                docker-compose==1.26.0 \
                dockerpty==0.4.1 \
                netaddr==0.7.19 \
                netifaces==0.10.9 \
                pycryptodome \
                psycopg2-binary \
                mock
                
ARG AP_DIR=/var/abc/sm

RUN mkdir -p $AP_DIR/log

ADD src/main/python $AP_DIR/python
ADD src/main/resources_hardcopy $AP_DIR/resources
ADD src/main/resources/certs $AP_DIR/resources/certs
ADD build.properties $AP_DIR

VOLUME /opt/abc/sm
VOLUME /opt/abc/apconn

RUN addgroup --system cloud && \
    adduser --system --disabled-password --ingroup cloud stackhelp
USER stackhelp
WORKDIR $AP_DIR/python

CMD ["../launch.sh"]
```

**The same python code has been working till 16 June 2021. Is there any recent changes in psycopg2 , psycopg2.extensions can cause this ?**

Following things tried, but did not work.

1. Updated python:3.7-alpine to python:alpine3.12
2. Postgres Container Updated to Postgres13

Comment: Possibly this https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/941

Answer (score 6):

[@Learner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68094667/2071807) is right.

Version 2.9.x [always starts a transaction when you connect to a database using a context manager](https://www.psycopg.org/articles/2021/06/16/psycopg-29-released/) like this:

```py
with psycopg2.connect(...) as connection:
    # This starts a transaction as of v2.9
    ...
```

Here's a quote from the release notes:

> `with connection` starts a transaction on autocommit transactions too (ticket [#941](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/941)).

This means that commands like `CREATE DATABASE` or `DROP DATABASE` can no longer be issued when connecting in this way.

Although the docs don't seem to offer an official solution to this problem, [it has been suggested](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/941#issuecomment-864025101) that the "new" way to do this is to use the "old" method of connecting to the database:

```py
try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(...)
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE foo")
finally:
    if connection:
        connection.close()
```

Comment: Example have a potential `NameError: name 'connection' is not defined` to be raised if `psycop2.connect` raises. Necessary to move `connect` out of `try`

Comment: `connection.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)` set to `AUTOCOMMIT` so no transaction block is created ✅

Comment: @SeanMcCarthy This is the only thing that worked for me. Thanks! you saved me

Answer (score 3):

psycopg2-binary has just released new version 2.9.1 and It might be due to it. https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/#history

Try and use older version 2.8.6 to check If it is working as before.